# Clear all cells from specified cell

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening,
I have a worksheet with this procedure:

```
Public Sub cleaning(list As String)
    Worksheets(list).Range("D5:XFD1048576").Clear
End Sub
```

It works and clear everything in range *D5:XFD1048576*, but I am quiet unsure if this is a good solution for my problem. I want a procedure to clear everything on the right of *D5* and down from *D5* cell.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I think it is fine. You could use `Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(5, "D"), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear` to cater for earlier versions of Excel that did not have as many rows / columns

Comment: thank you very much @Alex P , this is exactly what I was affraid of, earlier versions of Excel :) `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure does not solve problem descriebed. To do this, you need to clear all columns on the right side of column D (that means starting from E), and clear all rows below 5 (that means starting from row 6).

Here is piece of code that should work:

```
Public Sub extracleaning(list as String)
    Worksheets(list).Columns("E:XFD").Clear
    Worksheets(list).Rows("6:1048576").Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I used solution from @Alex P , my explanation of the problem wasnt exact, I mean starting from `D` and row `5` and I was not sure about position `XFD1048576` if it is the last cell in every excel worksheet